# Converting Image Map to Drupal Content

Tags: media

We have an old site that was are migrating to drupal. On the old site we have an image map: http://www.seguridadidl.org.pe/districts.html

Wondering if there is a more dynamic way of adding an image map such as this to drupal, rather than just adding the html in a node.

Does the "onMouseOver" work in Drupal?

Comment: what do you mean by "Does the "onMouseOver" work in Drupal"?

Comment: Couldn't see your imagemap - page looks broken: _"Página no encontrada La página "/districts.html" solicitada no se ha podido encontrar."_ - But the word _districts_ suggests this is a geographic map. If that's the case I would suggest you consider the many options for mapping in Drupal, here's a good module: https://drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc

Comment: Sorry, we moved the site. I should update this question and post our solution.

Comment: Now it is located here: /mapa/riesgos-y-recursos-preventivos-del-delito-lima-metropolitana-y-el-callao-2012

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Google Maps Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmaps) module is the right solution. Just parse or migrate your data into it.

> This project integrates the Google Maps API and Google Static Maps API. It makes possible to add addresses and/or coordinates (points) to nodes through CCK fields, display these geographical informations on node pages as text or interactive map or static map and use them on GeoRSS feeds. The project provides style plugins and row style plugins for views to build both interactive and static maps.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the image map to any full  HTML enabled text area... so you could drop it into content, put it in an text area field, or put it in a block. You can also drop it in a template file....

Answer (score 0):

An imagemap is just a set of coordinates that map a mouseover to an area in your map.

A quick google and I dont see any Drupal related imagemap modules. You could try to store coordinates as a field in your node. But, that sounds messy. An imagemap basically assumes a user has intimate knowledge of the image to properly build the coordinate sets.

`onMouseOver` is a Javascript event. HTML, CSS, the HTTP protocol, Javascript all work together to power the internet nowadays; so of course you can use Javascript code in a Drupal website. Drupal is simply a PHP CMS making use of all these things ... So long as the client browser supports it -- you're fine.

Comment: I have a related question:  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72313/using-js-maphilight-module-and-trying-to-trigger-a-hilight-from-an-external-ele

Comment: There is a jQuery maphilight module out there that we are using for this issue